# Is there a #define to determine whether reading an aligned 64-bit value will be atomic?

Tags: postgresql, posix, c89

In C code I have a 64-bit value in shared memory, accessed by different processes attached to that shared memory.  Currently reads and writes are covered by a spinlock, but in compiles where an aligned 64-bit read is guaranteed not to be "torn" (i.e., the read is atomic) I could omit the spinlock coverage since a "slightly stale" version of the value is fine.  The code needs to be able to compile on a wide variety of hardware (including 32 and 64 bit machines; Intel, AMD, Sparc Solaris, IBM Power7 and Power8, and many, many others), OS environments (including Linux, Windows, and HP-UX), and compilers (gcc and clang, many among others -- C89 or later); although it would be fine if I "punted" to keeping the spinlocks for environments where the safety of omitting them could not be positively confirmed.  Of course, the more safe platforms on which I can identify that it is safe, the better.

What is the safest and most portable way to determine whether such aligned 64-bit reads are guaranteed to be from a single 64-bit write?

Based on comments so far, it seems best to show some of the relevant code.

On my machine, in `src/include/pg_config.h`:

```c
/* src/include/pg_config.h.  Generated from pg_config.h.in by configure.  */
/* src/include/pg_config.h.in.  Generated from configure.in by autoheader.  */

[...]

/* Define to 1 if `long int' works and is 64 bits. */
#define HAVE_LONG_INT_64 1
```

A lot of such compile-time constants are defined based on what is found when `./configure` is run.

In `src/include/c.h`:

```c
/*
 * 64-bit integers
 */
#ifdef HAVE_LONG_INT_64
/* Plain "long int" fits, use it */

#ifndef HAVE_INT64
typedef long int int64;
#endif
#ifndef HAVE_UINT64
typedef unsigned long int uint64;
#endif
#elif defined(HAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64)
/* We have working support for "long long int", use that */

#ifndef HAVE_INT64
typedef long long int int64;
#endif
#ifndef HAVE_UINT64
typedef unsigned long long int uint64;
#endif
#else
/* neither HAVE_LONG_INT_64 nor HAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64 */
#error must have a working 64-bit integer datatype
#endif
```

The code I'm trying to improve is below.  `oldSnapshotControl` is a pointer to a structure in shared memory, and `threshold_timestamp` is a field in that structure, defined as `int64`.  Note the `XXX` block in the comment for the function.

```c
/*
 * Get timestamp through which vacuum may have processed based on last stored
 * value for threshold_timestamp.
 *
 * XXX: If we can trust a read of an int64 value to be atomic, we can skip the
 * spinlock here.
 */
int64
GetOldSnapshotThresholdTimestamp(void)
{
    int64       threshold_timestamp;

    SpinLockAcquire(&oldSnapshotControl->mutex_threshold);
    threshold_timestamp = oldSnapshotControl->threshold_timestamp;
    SpinLockRelease(&oldSnapshotControl->mutex_threshold);

    return threshold_timestamp;
}
```

Comment: Search for `stdatomic.h`. Better directly use `_Atomic`..

Comment: stdatomic.h and _Atomic don't seem to be present in gcc, so that's not very portable.

Comment: It is very much portable, as it is part of C11 standard. Use a recent version of gcc (since 4.9.something) and you will find it. If you use an external header, you will get support for them also in gcc 4.7 & 4.8. That file uses builtins to provide `_Atomic` and the required definitions. IIRC, it is a BSD-port (it does not depend on BSD, though).

Comment: By portable, I mean that the project this code is for requires that it be able to compile on C89.  ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-requirements.html )  We may soon bump that up to C99, but not any time *real* soon.  The product is still compiled and used on some very old machines.

Comment: Also, support for `stdatomic.h` is optional, even in C11.

Comment: Well, if you are off the standard, you should have mentioned that. Sticking with the C standard is certainly the most portable way you can get.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Tell me one 64 bit C11 compiler which does not provide stdatomics. Do you know a more portable way? And gcc provides the header/features for at least major 32 and 64 bit target architectures (ARM, x86, etc)

Comment: @Olaf, no one mentioned 64-bit compilers, just 64-bit values.

Comment: @IanAbbott: See the tags! On a 64 bit architecture I think it is logical to imply a 64 bit target compiler.

Comment: Well, let's not waste time and space arguing about the definition of portable too much.  The suggested include and test are not present in gcc on an up-to-date installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, much less the wide variety of environments it needs to compile in.  It needs to port to some old compilers, at least in terms of a clean compile.  I won't complain if it never says 64-bit atomic reads are an option in such environments.

Comment: Question edited to provide more examples about the environments on which the solution must get a clean compile.

Comment: You should remove the `64bit` tag to keep @Olaf happy, since it appears to have been added incorrectly.

Comment: @IanAbbott, done.  Obviously I can't exclude the spinlock on a system without 64-bit memory access -- the question is about what compile-time tests can be made that port to a wide variety of environments to determine whether I am *on* such a system, so it seemed an appropriate tag; but if it's causing confusion, I'll drop it.

Comment: Although a variable may be read in one go, reordering may still cause problems; is even that not a problem?

Comment: You can do compile-time, positive tests that you are on such a system. You'd need to do pre-processor checks such as `#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L) && !defined(__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__)`. However, an `_Atomic`-qualified integer type is not guaranteed to have the same size, alignment, or representation as the unqualified integer type.

Comment: @black: No, in this case any fairly-recent value will do; adding a memory barrier would cost more than it is worth.

Comment: @IanAbbott: thanks for the heads up on size.  I will update the question with more context about the type and how it is currently defined.  Perhaps that will allow a more direct answer.

Comment: @kgrittn: But they **are**! It's just the header missing and that can be found by a simple search. They are even avail in 4.7 - I should know, as I used them since 4.7.2 .

Comment: @IanAbbott, kgrittn: See the tag description if th 64bit tag- It is about 64 bit OS, not 64 bit datatypes. And, yes you **can** avoid a spinlock. Shooting sparrows with a cannon.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Please post your `#if defined`... suggestion as an answer, so I can up-vote it and mark it correct.  Perhaps it can be expanded to work with some non-C11 compilers, too; but using what you suggested I can drop the spinlock where that is safe for a C11 compiler (which most will be) without breaking portability to other supported platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Before C11, no read of any data type but perhaps `sig_atomic_t` is guarateed to be atomic (in the sense that you address it), it is simply not part of the language, and C as of that version can never guarantee that. And there are plenty of platforms around where in fact it wouldn't be atomic.

Since C11 you have atomics (in a broader sense) included in the language, and newer version of gcc and clang support that feature. This is the way if you want portable code, that will be future proof.

If you are satisfied with less portability, you could use gcc's builtin extensions starting with `__sync_` that basically do atomic operations on the basic integer types. Here you have macros `__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_XX` with `XX` replaced by the width in number of bytes, that tell you if such an operation is supported.

These gcc extensions are around for a long time, and clang has them, too.

Comment: Just to be clear, building with a C11 compiler is not *prohibited*; but the code must compile without warning or error on C89.  There are a lot of constants we define differently based on the hardware, OS. or compiler.

Comment: I'm not interested in covering atomic CAS, etc. -- that's already been done in this code.  Oddly, what hasn't been is handling the case of a simple read or write with no memory barrier in an atomic fashion where possible.  It doesn't appear that __sync_ is necessary or helpful with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sig_atomic_t`

> which is the (possibly volatile-qualified) integer type of an object
>   that can be accessed as an atomic entity, even in the presence of
>   asynchronous interrupts.

found from C89 onward. In the `<stdint.h>` header, the following macros are defined

```
SIG_ATOMIC_MIN
SIG_ATOMIC_MAX
```

however, only from C99 (your compiler may have similar implementation-defined macros). Then simply `#if SIG_ATOMIC_MAX == 64BIT_MAX`; `64BIT_MAX` can in turn be found by using implementation-defined macros, `limits.h` or both, with a couple of `#if`-s and `#define`-s.

Although you're guaranteed `sig_atomic_t` will be atomic, it may be smaller than 64 bits: on my 64 bits platform `sig_atomic_t` is still `int`, for example.

Probably the simplest solution would be relying on external tools (like cmake, autotools and so on) and have them find that out for you.